# Tagged items listing layout after clicking on a tag is displayed on homepage

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, tags, layout

I have installed a **Cloud Tags** module to display most used tags on my site. I would expect that when clicking on any of the Tags on the module, to see a page with a list layout that will show all relative content items and articles that are tagged with the clicked tag.

Indeed I am seeing this list but the problem is that this list layout is displayed on the homepage under all modules that exist on homepage.

Why is this happening and how to display the tags layout page on its own and not as part of the homepage with all these modules?

Comment: Hi @marc and welcome. Please try to explain better what your problem is and what you are trying to do. Do note that your question as is, isn't containing any obvious question - so it's unclear what the question is. Since you are new on this site - note that this is not a forum - read here: **[help]** - and also that in your question the "I am new, need some help.. " and anything that isn't making your question a better and more clear question are irrelevant/ excessive.

Comment: I kind of get what you are trying to ask, but please give us more information. For example, what tag module are you using? What configuration are you using for that module? Where exactly do you want the cloud tags to show? Where are they currently shown? Etc The more info the better.

Comment: After reading your question some more times, it also started getting clearer to me as well - but initially I had trouble understanding what is all about. I will try an edit on your question to make it clearer. Please consider editing it back if I am wrong and if so provide more details about your problem.

Comment: I will also try to answer based on my understanding of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

## Why this is happening?

This is happening (showing the tags list page on homepage) because there is no menu item for this particular view. So Joomla, because it needs a menu item for each component's view, will use the default (homepage) menu item to display the relative content of the tags component.

Obviously your homepage's menu item has assigned on it many modules that are positioned above the component output, and likely in its standard condition is set to not display Joomla content at all - e.g. a featured articles menu item that is set to display 0 articles - or maybe you have a single article menu item, which shows your home article below these modules.

But when you click on any of the tags, the module is linking to a view of the tags component - and without a dedicated menu item for that view it will default to the homepage. So at the moment, your request will be slightly different than when you actually see your real homepage. If you had disableb SEF URLs you would see in that URL something like:

```
index.php?option=com_tags&...&itemid=101...
```

with the itemid being the id of your home page, which will force to load all modules of the homepage at their current module positions on the template, but this time mixed with the content of the tags component.

## Solution

To overcome this, you simply need to create a menu item for that specific view of your tags component. If the module is well designed, then normally when you click on any of the tags, Joomla will find a dedicated menu item to display your tagged items list layout on its own and not under the homepage's menu item. You will be able to tell to Joomla what modules you will like to display for that view as well.

### Hidden Menu Item

If you don't want to show that new menu item for the tags under any of your visible menus - then you can create a hidden menu/menu item.

#### Helpful resources for further reading:

- [**How to control module display when linking to an article with no menu item**](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_control_module_display_when_linking_to_an_article_with_no_menu_item)
- [**Using Hidden Menus**](https://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-mar-2014/item/1790-using-hidden-menus)
- [**Joomla Menu Documentation**](https://docs.joomla.org/Menu)